# Is there a way to change my browser view from desktop to mobile in python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have been coding using selenium in python to automate my browsing and found some websites work better in mobile view. Because of this, I would like to automatically be able to change between desktop and mobile view using python. I have done quite a bit of research online and have not found any examples of this. Any help would be great.

Comment: well all basic mobile version starts by putting 'm' berfore the url